Terraform Glue plugin not respond
Error: Plugin did not respond
│
│   with module.glue-test.aws_glue_job.main[0],
│   on ..\main.tf line 25, in resource "aws_glue_job" "main":
│   25: resource "aws_glue_job" "main" {
│
│ The plugin encountered an error, and failed to respond to the plugin.(*GRPCProvider).ApplyResourceChange call.    
│ The plugin logs may contain more details.

Stack trace from the terraform-provider-aws_v5.46.0_x5.exe plugin:

panic: interface conversion: interface {} is nil, not map[string]interface {}

goroutine 104 [running]:
github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/internal/service/glue.expandDatabasePrincipalPermission(0xc00201a270)   
        github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/internal/service/glue/catalog_database.go:464 +0x23c
github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/internal/service/glue.expandDatabasePrincipalPermissions({0xc002001990?, 0x1, 0xc?})
        github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/internal/service/glue/catalog_database.go:440 +0x8b
github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/internal/service/glue.resourceCatalogDatabaseCreate({0x143fefa8, 0xc001922cf0}, 0x1?, {0x128062a0?, 0xc0045d5e10?})
        github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/internal/service/glue/catalog_database.go:184 +0x634
github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/internal/provider.New.(*wrappedResource).Create.interceptedHandler[...].func8(0x0?, {0x128062a0?, 0xc0045d5e10?})
        github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/internal/provider/intercept.go:113 +0x283
github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2/helper/schema.(*Resource).create(0x143fefa8?, {0x143fefa8?, 0xc0040885d0?}, 0xd?, {0x128062a0?, 0xc0045d5e10?})
        github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2@v2.33.0/helper/schema/resource.go:773 +0x7a
github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2/helper/schema.(*Resource).Apply(0xc00169f420, {0x143fefa8, 0xc0040885d0}, 0xc003f249c0, 0xc001494a00, {0x128062a0, 0xc0045d5e10})
        github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2@v2.33.0/helper/schema/resource.go:909 +0xa89
github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2/helper/schema.(*GRPCProviderServer).ApplyResourceChange(0xc00147a048, {0x143fefa8?, 0xc004138600?}, 0xc000071d10)
        github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2@v2.33.0/helper/schema/grpc_provider.go:1078 +0xdbc
github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-mux/tf5muxserver.(*muxServer).ApplyResourceChange(0x143fefe0?, {0x143fefa8?, 0xc004138270?}, 0xc000071d10)
        github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-mux@v0.15.0/tf5muxserver/mux_server_ApplyResourceChange.go:36 +0x193  
github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-go/tfprotov5/tf5server.(*server).ApplyResourceChange(0xc00093d220, {0x143fefa8?, 0xc001c3ff50?}, 0xc000dd21c0)
        github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-go@v0.22.1/tfprotov5/tf5server/server.go:846 +0x3d0
github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-go/tfprotov5/internal/tfplugin5._Provider_ApplyResourceChange_Handler({0x125a20a0?, 0xc00093d220}, {0x143fefa8, 0xc001c3ff50}, 0xc0002df380, 0x0)
        github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-go@v0.22.1/tfprotov5/internal/tfplugin5/tfplugin5_grpc.pb.go:518 +0x169
google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).processUnaryRPC(0xc001652200, {0x143fefa8, 0xc001c3fec0}, {0x1443ee58, 0xc004403860}, 0xc001cdaea0, 0xc004425020, 0x1c92acf8, 0x0)
        google.golang.org/grpc@v1.62.1/server.go:1386 +0xe23
google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).handleStream(0xc001652200, {0x1443ee58, 0xc004403860}, 0xc001cdaea0)
        google.golang.org/grpc@v1.62.1/server.go:1797 +0x100c
google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).serveStreams.func2.1()
        google.golang.org/grpc@v1.62.1/server.go:1027 +0x8b
created by google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).serveStreams.func2 in goroutine 27
        google.golang.org/grpc@v1.62.1/server.go:1038 +0x135

Error: The terraform-provider-aws_v5.46.0_x5.exe plugin crashed!

When i am trying to terraform init, its successful. But when i run terraform apply it give above error plugin crashed.
I have also checked with TF_LOG=Debug but there also it is showing plugin crashed.
Is there any solution?

checked using different AWS version and Terraform version, but no luck.


It could be a bug in the latest provider version, since it was released recently.

I am also getting similar error.
